# Import private key to coinbase?

Tags: private-key, coinbase.com

Is there a way to import a private key that I have been using in bitcoin-qt to my coinbase wallet?

Answer (score 8):

Coinbase no longer supports any sort of wallet import (wonder why?). To quote Coinbase (June 2016 on https://support.coinbase.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2285419-how-do-i-import-an-existing-wallet-)

> Coinbase wallets currently do not support a wallet import feature. If you have paper wallets, private keys, wallet.dat files, or brain wallets, they can be imported into another wallet (Bitcoin QT, Electrum, Multibit, Armory, Blockchain.info, etc) before being sent to your Coinbase wallet.
>   After you have imported your wallet, you can keep your bitcoin there, or send it to one of your Coinbase wallet addresses.

Answer (score 3):

At [Import Paper Wallet](https://coinbase.com/paper_imports), you can import a private key. Though it's made for their paper wallet exports, it will work with any valid private key. Using it will transfer the money from the private key into Coinbase, not just allow you to send from it using Coinbase (like adding a private key to Bitcoin-QT would).

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly, it will: (1) sweep the existing balance of the private key to my coinbase balance (so the address will then show zero) and (2) sweep new transactions sent to that address to my coinbase balance?

Comment: Answer to 1 is yes. I'm unsure about 2, I'd guess yes.

Comment: Looks like Coinbase has disabled this functionality, as the "Import Paper Wallet" link just redirects to the history page. :(

Comment: note that this feature has been turned on and off intermittently. But it only supports uncompressed keys (those starting with 5). It does not support compressed keys (starting with a K or L) or BIP0038 encrypted keys.

Comment: It does not do (2).

Answer (score 1):

I used BitPay's Android app to sweep a paper wallet. You might want to adjust the wallet's fee settings first.

Note that while the BTC got swept, (minus a tx fee) the Bitcoin Cash did not get swept, even though the BitPay app supports Bitcoin Cash and the paper wallet was pre-fork, since the sweep was a new, post-fork tx.

I was able to sweep the Bitcoin Cash from the paper wallet into a Electron-Cash for Mac by manually typing the private key.

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin SE!  How does this answer the OP's question of importing a private key into Coinbase?  As it stands, this doesn't provide a solution and doesn't answer the question.  I recommend editing it to explain how your solution can be used to achieve what the OP asked about.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I need to sweep the Bitcoins in my paper wallet to send them somewhere else, but I have to keep the Bitcoin Gold coins there (this is a pre-fork paper wallet) until the BTG team actually releases the software.