# How to move paper wallet funds to another wallet

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet

I have an old paper wallet and private key.

I want to transfer bitcoin from this wallet to another wallet? How can I accomplish this?

I tried this on coinbase for example by going to:

1. I click “Receive”
2. A QR pops up with my coinbase wallet address

The problem is there is no place to input or transact where I want to receive bitcoin from.

What is the easiest way to transfer BTC from wallet to another? (I’m also a developer so API, code, etc work for me as well).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import private key to coinbase?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21553/import-private-key-to-coinbase)

Comment: @m1xolyd1an I’m just wondering why this seems to not have more clarity, wouldn’t this be the most rudimentary task when it comes to moving around BTC?

Comment: It is, which is why there are many other posts on this site with the same question. It's quite simple. You sweep the funds to a wallet you control, and then you can send the funds from that wallet you swept to then to coinbase or whichever exchange you want.

Comment: @m1xolyd1an I know how it theoretically works, but it isn’t that easy.  For example, you can’t move a paper wallet to coinbase.  You can’t from most other exchanges as well.